# How to open photoviewer for multiple images in android?

Tags: android, image, photo, photo-gallery

In my android app, I can get the path to a folder of images (or could be empty folder) in the phone memory. I want to then open the photo gallery app, and make it display the images in the folder. By default it can display at any of the images. But I want the user to be able to swipe left/right to switch images, and also zoom in/out and pan around.

Is this possible to do in android and if so how can I do that?

Thanks

This is my code:

I debugged it, and it runs all the lines of the code below, then crashes.

file - `/storage/sdcard0/arin/category/1`

uri - `file:///storage/sdcard0/arin/category/1`

```
            String localimagelink = "arin/category/" + Integer.toString(Fish.this.getId(), 10);
            File file = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), localimagelink);
            if (file.exists()) {
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);

                Context context = button.getContext();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri); 
                context.startActivity(intent); 
            }
```

Log:

```
08-05 23:30:12.275: E/AndroidRuntime(13069): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 23:30:12.275: E/AndroidRuntime(13069): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///storage/sdcard0/arin/category/1 }
08-05 23:30:12.275: E/AndroidRuntime(13069):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1580)
08-05 23:30:12.275: E/AndroidRuntime(13069):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1431)
08-05 23:30:12.275: E/AndroidRuntime(13069):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3417)
08-05 23:30:12.275: E/AndroidRuntime(13069):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3378)
08-05 23:30:12.275: E/AndroidRuntime(13069):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3588)
08-05 23:30:12.275: E/AndroidRuntime(13069):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3556)
08-05 23:30:12.275: E/AndroidRuntime(13069):    at fish.Fish$5.onClick(Fish.java:323)
08-05 23:30:12.275: E/AndroidRuntime(13069):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4192)
08-05 23:30:12.275: E/AndroidRuntime(13069):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17254)
08-05 23:30:12.275: E/AndroidRuntime(13069):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-05 23:30:12.275: E/AndroidRuntime(13069):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-05 23:30:12.275: E/AndroidRuntime(13069):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-05 23:30:12.275: E/AndroidRuntime(13069):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
08-05 23:30:12.275: E/AndroidRuntime(13069):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 23:30:12.275: E/AndroidRuntime(13069):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-05 23:30:12.275: E/AndroidRuntime(13069):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
08-05 23:30:12.275: E/AndroidRuntime(13069):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
08-05 23:30:12.275: E/AndroidRuntime(13069):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to modify the behaviour of the photo gallery app?

Comment: no, basically I want to create an intent to open the photo gallery app, but pass in the path to where it should display the images from.

Comment: Also, this is not to pick a picture, I just want users to see images.

Comment: Do you already know the path of the folder?

Comment: yes, I added all the details above.